# How to change TV channels programmatically on Android TV

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-tv

I am developing an application for Android TV where i need to change TV channels programmatically (Channel up and down), for that i need available channel list on TV input source. Is there any way that returns available channels and change them programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the channels easily by inserting the channel see https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/channel#java

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(Channels.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NUMBER, channel.number);
values.put(Channels.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, channel.name);
values.put(Channels.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NETWORK_ID, channel.originalNetworkId);
values.put(Channels.COLUMN_TRANSPORT_STREAM_ID, channel.transportStreamId);
values.put(Channels.COLUMN_SERVICE_ID, channel.serviceId);
values.put(Channels.COLUMN_VIDEO_FORMAT, channel.videoFormat);

Uri uri = context.getContentResolver().insert(TvContract.Channels.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

However its not possible to change channels nor is there has been any official documentation on switching channels thus not possible or recommended officially.

Comment: Is this solution will work with all kind of TV application or only for  Android system TV app?. Because we are creating a normal TV application and wants to control channels from there.

Comment: @ManjuKumari Did you find any useful resources to achieve the same?